# Pulling Data from Multiple Tables from SQL in Angular

Tags: angular, stored-procedures, datatables, get

I have been given a stored procedure to pull/GET count data from 4 different tables in SQL. I have my API set up to run that stored procedure correctly. However, the way I have my Angular set up currently only works with one table at a time. The GET method works as follows:

```
   List(): Observable<any[]>
  {
    return this.http.get<any[]>('API/' + *INSERT TABLE NAME HERE*)
  }
```

and appears as follows in the Network tab for GET:

```
https://localhost:44444/API/*TABLENAME*
```

How would I go about doing this with a stored procedure that uses 4 different tables? Or am I thinking about this incorrectly?

Comment: Just a thought - If someone has given a stored procedure and api for a new requirement then why cant you change the angular to call new API for the new requirement?

Comment: I definitely can change the Angular. I'm just not sure how to tackle this issue. I was told to reference objects rather than tables. However, I'm not sure how to do something like that for HTTP calls.

Comment: pass the table name related to table and api.                                  
`List(tablename:string): Observable<any[]>
  {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(``API/${tablename}``)
  }`    use only one ` in (`API/${tablename}`)